# Декларация функции в цикле for

Tags: javascript

Является ли декларация функции в цикле `for` антипаттерном, ведущим к каким нибудь реальным негативным последствиям?

```
function foo(x) {
  //много кода, где bar не используется
  for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    (function() {
      function bar() {
        //код bar
      }
      bar();
    })();
  }
  //много кода, где bar не используется
}
```

Comment: пример приведите

Comment: @Igor добавил пример

Comment: @Igor пример был не совсем удачным, я его видоизменил — посмотрите сейчас.

Comment: 1 - зачем тут IIFE?  Что бы скрыть функцию bar? 2 - да, у вас каждый раз будет создаваться новая функция, если это цикл из тысячи элементов, тысячу раз создаться новая функция, которая занимает место. Пусть даже позже GC ее удалить, зачем изначально плодить?

Comment: @ThisMan здесь IIFE потому что Igor попросил пример для общей задачи, и мне пришлось выдумывать его на скорую руку, чтобы изобразить необходимое поведение.

Comment: @ThisMan ваш ответ это то что я и хотел получить. Можете пояснить к чему может привести такое «размножение» функции, и опасно ли это при небольшом числе итераций цикла for. Так же можете пояснить будет ли это действовать так же при обявлении функции bar через let bar = function(){}?

Comment: @ThisMan, все может быть не так однозначно и зависеть от конкретной реализации Js движка, а так же реально используемого кода